# "We're sorry something went wrong that might make Powerpoint unstable" still hapenning

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When saving certain presentation files, I get the error message "we're sorry something went wrong that might make powerpoint unstable", and/or that the file cannot be saved because it is read-only. The file is, of course, not in fact read-only, if I check its attributes.

Restarting Powerpoint or the PC, or working with Powerpoint started in safe mode, does not help. I can only save that file if I undo enough many steps (and thus lose a lot of work). That 'critical' step in the undo list beyond which saving is possible is however nothing fancy, e.g. just inserting some text.

It could be that the problem is due to some content in it having been created in an older version of PPT, as suggested [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_win10-mso_365hp/were-sorry-something-went-wrong-that-might-make/68b76345-e135-4905-81da-267806b4eb89). But if I select all the contents of the file and copy-paste into a new powerpoint file (even saved in the old PPT format), then after a while the same error message appears, which makes me think this is not a file-related problem but a more general bug.

Other forum messages suggest this might be related to Dropbox or GSuite being installed, but I don't have those.

Any suggestions? Am using Powerpoint 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: See https://windowsreport.com/something-went-wrong-that-might-make-powerpoint-unstable-solved/ and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_win10-mso_365hp/were-sorry-something-went-wrong-that-might-make/68b76345-e135-4905-81da-267806b4eb89

Comment: Thanks. I had seen those posts before I posted mine. I hadn't tried the Export option - tried it now, seems to allow me to save, but will report back whether the error comes back after a while (as it's been the case to date)